# How to use the alias interceptor for the properties of utility class object in action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, alias, model-driven

I have an `Action` class named `MyFirstClass` in which I have a `String` variable and a `User` variable as follows:

```
public class MyFirstClass extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>,Preparable {

    User user;
    
    private String nickName;

    public void prepare(){
       user = new User();       
    }

    public User getModel(){
       return user;
    }
    .........................
    ........................    
}
```

The `User` class has `String` variables as `userName` and `userAge`.

As my `Action` class has implemented `ModelDriven` interface, the variables of the `User` class are supposed to get/set on the request.

**I have a JSP file also which is designed as follows:**

```
<s:form action="index">
<s:actionerror/>
<s:textfield name="myname" label="UserName:">
</s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="myage" label="UserAge:">
</s:textfield>
<s:submit key="submit" name="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

**and `struts.xml` is designed as:**

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index" class="com.actionClasses.MyFirstClass">
            <param name="aliases">#{'myname':'nickName','myname':user.userName,'myage':user.age}</param>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/> 
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>        
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/user.jsp</result>                
        </action>
</package>
```

**My problem is:**

Since my JSP page text fields' name do not match with the property names in the `User` class. I am not able to set the request parameters, like this, to the corresponding properties in the action with the help of `alias` interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

Change the configuration for aliases to match property names, also use `defaultStack` you need it because it contains [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html).

You have stated

> **`User`** class has String variables as **`userName`** and **`userAge`**.

If the form is like

**user.jsp:**

```
<s:form action="index">
<s:actionerror/>
<s:textfield name="name" label="UserName:">
</s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="age" label="UserAge:">
</s:textfield>
<s:submit key="submit" name="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

and result is

**success.jsp:**

```
<s:actionerror/>
<s:label name="userName" label="UserName:"/><br/>
<s:label name="userAge" label="UserAge:"/><br/>
```

**the configuration should be:**

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="index" class="com.actionClasses.MyFirstClass">
        <param name="aliases">#{'name':'userName','age':'userAge'}</param>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>        
        <interceptor-ref name="alias"/> 
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/user.jsp</result>                
    </action>
</package>
```

---

The [`alias` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/alias-interceptor.html) is at the end because it should be after `modelDriven`.

Comment: userName and userAge are not the properties of my action class,they belong to the **User** class. Thats why,above solution is not working.Any other way.....??

Comment: I think this line,**<param name="aliases">#{'name':'userName','age':'userAge'}</param>**, states that if the user submits a page,containing values for 'name' and 'age',then these values should hit the setters of 'userName' and 'userAge' of the landing action class(MyFirstClass) itself and not in  any bean class. In my scenario,**MyFirstClass** is an action class and **User** is a bean class inside this action.....This soln. is still not working.

Comment: Actually hit the `valueStack` and if your action is `ModelDriven` the model is affected.